# Dynamically adding / removing comments in Python ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

I've spent a bit of time researching this and I'm coming up blank.

I'm totally new to Python and I'm trying to step through my xml file and essentially if something is not active comment out a particular element, if active uncomment again. The check for active or not is fine, is just the subsequent commenting in or out I'm hit the wall on. I'm using python 2.7

my structure is fairly simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta name="a" content="some stuff" />
    <meta name="b" content="things and stuff" />
    <meta name="c" content="rubbish stuff" />
    <groupStuff id="foo">
      <meta name="thing" content="wibble" />
    </groupStuff>
    <groupStuff id="bar">
      <meta name="thing" content="bibble" />
    </groupStuff>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</smil>
```

So if inactive comment out  node, then if active bring back.

I assumed this would be fairly straight forward and probably is but I'm totally stuck

Answer (score 0):

You could technically replace an element with a comment node of its string representation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.XML("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta name="a" content="some stuff" />
    <meta name="b" content="things and stuff" />
    <meta name="c" content="rubbish stuff" />
    <groupStuff id="foo">
      <meta name="thing" content="wibble" />
    </groupStuff>
    <groupStuff id="bar">
      <meta name="thing" content="bibble" />
    </groupStuff>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</smil>""")

parent = root.findall(".//*[@name='a']/..")[0]
child = parent.findall(".//*[@name='a']")[0]

commented = ET.tostring(child)

parent.remove(child)
parent.append(ET.Comment(commented))

print ET.tostring(root)
```

You can use `insert` instead of `append` if the order matters.

Uncommenting might require to have some markers distinguishing disabled elements from genuine comments. but basically you'd be parsing the comment data as its own element and replacing it into the tree in a similar way.